# DataGridView DateTime column string was not recognized as a valid DateTime DataError

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with a `DataTable` as its `DataSource`.  In the `DataTable`, I have a column with a `DataType` of `DateTime`.  The `DataTable` is successfully filled from `SQL Server` using a `SqlDataAdapter`.

I am using:

```
dgv.Columns(j).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HHmm"
```

as the format for the pertinent `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` and the data loads fine and is displayed in this desired format correctly.

However, whenever I make valid (or invalid) edits to one of the cells in this column, I always get the error:

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>   at System.DateTime.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)... please handle the DataError event.

I'm quite surprised that simply specifying the default cell style format isn't enough for the `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` to properly nail down the values that the user inputs.  So, my question is: is there some other event/place where it would be appropriate (and necessary) to specify some kind of `CellValue = DateTime.TryParseExact(blah blah)` correction-statement?  I was thinking of doing so in the `CellValidating`, `CellValidated`, or `DataError` events.  I'd do the testing, but it really feels like I'm missing a simpler solution here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the format you want is non-standard, you have to help provide the logic for parsing it and displaying it. One way is to write some code in the `CellFormatting` and `CellParsing` events.

Another way is to specify an `IFormatProvider` object. *Typically* these just do the formatting and you still may need code for parsing, but with a few extra lines of code, the `FormatProvider` can do that too:

```
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class DGVOddDateFormatter
    Implements IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter

    Private myFmt As String = "dd/MM/yyyy HHmm"
    Private mydgv As DataGridView
    Private myNDX As Int32 = -1

    Public Sub New(ctl As DataGridView, fmt As String, colNdx As Int32)
        mydgv = ctl
        myFmt = fmt
        myNDX = colNdx

        AddHandler mydgv.CellParsing, AddressOf dgv_CellParsing
        mydgv.Columns(colNdx).DefaultCellStyle.Format = fmt
    End Sub

    Private Sub dgv_CellParsing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs)
        If e.ColumnIndex = myNDX Then
            Dim dt As DateTime
            If DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Value.ToString(), 
                           myFmt, Nothing, 
                           DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
                e.Value = dt
                e.ParsingApplied = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function Format(format1 As String, 
                           arg As Object, 
                           formatProvider As IFormatProvider) As String _
                                  Implements ICustomFormatter.Format

        Dim dt As DateTime

        If TypeOf (arg) Is DateTime Then
            dt = CType(arg, DateTime)
            Return dt.ToString(myFmt)
        Else
            Return ""    ' or other default value
        End If


    End Function

    Public Function GetFormat(formatType As Type) As Object Implements IFormatProvider.GetFormat
        If TypeOf formatType Is ICustomFormatter Then
            Return Me
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

When the formatter is created, it hooks into the `CellParsing` event to provide the complementary logic to convert the contents back to a valid `DateTime`.

### Usage

```
dgv1.DataSource = dtSample

dgv1.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = New DGVOddDateFormatter(dgv1, 
                  "dd/MM/yyyy HHmm", 4)
```

Without an `IFormatProvider`, you'd use the same code in the `CellParsing` and `CellFormatting` events, but you'd have to replicate it on other grids which may also use an odd format.  Since the formatter is passed the format to use, it is reusable.

---

In this case, the DGV could do the parsing and formatting itself since all it needs is the format string which it has.  But in other cases such as converting an epoch type date (seconds since some arbitrary date) it would have no clue.  So, they provided the means for you to create and use your own `IFormatProvider`.  These can be used with other things like `Enum` transforms, `TimeSpan` formatting, etc.

Comment: Genius.  @Plutonix is my `DataGridView` hero.  
For others' sake, consider editing in an `Imports System.Globalization` 1st line at the top of your code.

Comment: Yeah, I clipped it from the fully qualified `Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None` ref to reduce HScroll.  Added